# Req.body returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms, express

req.body returns undefined in this part

```
res.send("Texto "+req.body.titulo+" Conteudo "+req.body.conteudo)
```

the result is Texto undefined Conteudo undefined

Why is this happening?
I tried using app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })) app.use(bodyParser.json()) instead of expres, but bodyParser is deprecated.

index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Post = require('./models/Post');

// Config
    // Template Engine
    app.engine('handlebars', handlebars({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
    app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

    // Body Parser
    app.use(express.json({limit:'20mb'}));
    app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false, limit:'20mb'}));

// Rotas
    app.get('/cad', function(req, res){
        res.render('formularios');
    });

    app.post('/add', function(req, res){
        res.send("Texto "+req.body.titulo+" Conteudo "+req.body.conteudo);
      
    });

app.listen(8081, function(){
    console.log("Servidor rodando na URL http://localhost:8081");
});
```

here is the code that posts to /add. formularios.handlebars:

```
<form action="/add" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="titulo">Título:</label>
        <input type="text" name="titulo" id="titulo_id">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="conteudo">Conteúdo:</label>
        <input type="text" name="conteudo" id="conteudo_id">
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <button type="submit">Cadastrar postagem</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that posts to /add?

Comment: use app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
    app.use(bodyParser.json()) instead

Comment: bodyParser is deprecated and it gives the same result

Comment: I have tried your app using what you provided and it responded as expected: `Texto asd Conteudo asd`.  There's more you didn't provided?

Comment: It's working now, i have no idea why. I'm running the same code and now i'm getting the correct result. ??????????????????????????